# Does a ternary operator has a return value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements, operators, return-value, ternary

on MDN documentation,
I did not find the return value of the ternary operator(along with parameters descript) in syntax,
it specifies an expression to execute on true,
or an expression to execute on false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

question is :
does a ternary operator returns a value or not?

Comment: An *operator* returns a value, yes, that's its primary purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Return statement ends function execution and provides requested value. So if you want to *return* from the function, you basically use ternary operator on the right side of `return`:

```
function foo() {
 let testValue;
 return testValue ? 'defined' : 'undefined'; // returns 'undefined', because variable was declared, but not initialized by any value, which transformed by engine as false value
}
```

But you can't decide if you want to return or not to return based on some condition:

```
function bar () {
 let testValue;
 testValue ? console.log('defined') : return 'undefined'; // false condition won't work
}
```

If you need to decide whether you want to continue computations or return some value based on some condition, it is better to use basic `if` statement.

---

Edit: Thanks to @deceze who mentioned that return is not an operator, but an actual statement.

Comment: `return` is a *statement*, not an operator. That's the reason you can't use it like in the second example.

Comment: More to the point, a [statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements) cannot be used where an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#expressions) is expected.